# Connection could not be established with host laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel

i am using virtual host but phpmyadmin is also pointed to virtual host ip and working perfectly

when i register a account on my laravel project i am getting following error .

```
 Connection could not be established with host [No connection could be
   made because the target machine actively refused it.
     #10061]
```

in my logs

```
#10061] in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:268
Stack trace:
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the DB_HOSTNAME in your .env and what is the hostname in your phpmyadmin? And are they hosted in the same virtual environment? you probably need to connect to localhost in .env and to http://192.168.10.10 in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Your mail settings probably have the wrong port

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by having the wrong values configured for `MAIL_PORT`, `MAIL_ENCRYPTION`, and occasionally `MAIL_HOST`.

swiftmailer is the library that sends email. You're getting the error when you register and Laravel tries to send an email.

`"...the target machine actively refused..."` means that the host resolved successfully, but the other computer either has a firewall blocking the port or no process is listening on that port.

Your mailer service should tell you what port to use in their documentation. If using `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` and `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`, typically this will be port 587, 465, or 25.